# How to restrict particular User for custom pick list in account

Tags: administration

I have a custom Pick list field on Account. I need to restrict one user to edit that record. How can i achieve this? Should i write validation rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present specyfic picklist values for users you should use record types functionality.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recordtype.htm&type=0

--edit
If you want to hide field for particular user(eg. profile) you can use field level security.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=0

Comment: Not profile level. I need to restrict another profile user. Using FLS we can restrict filed access at profile level only. But i need to restrict any other user.

Comment: After all, each user have a profile. Why you not be able to hide the fields on all profiles and add the access on permission set?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate profile for this special user and then use FLS.